# I need help to set up Reddit API

Tags: java, github, reddit

I tried to set up the Reddit API in Linux Mint 16, so that I can use it in IntelliJ 13.1.2/Java.
So I used this guide: https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/Install-guide
and started with

```
$ git clone https://github.com/reddit/reddit.git
```

next I went to r2

```
$ cd reddit/r2
```

, but when I tried to do the next 3 lines:

```
$ python setup.py build

$ sudo python setup.py develop

$ make
```

my console gave out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    pkg_resources.require("distribute>=0.6.16")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 696, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute>=0.6.16
```

respectively

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 35, in <module>
    pkg_resources.require("distribute>=0.6.16")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 696, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 594, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: distribute>=0.6.16
```

and in the end at the "make" command the console gave out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Makefile.py", line 24, in <module>
    from r2.lib.translation import I18N_PATH
  File "/home/fox/reddit/r2/r2/lib/translation.py", line 28, in <module>
    from babel.messages.extract import extract_javascript
ImportError: No module named babel.messages.extract
Makefile:41: *** Makefile.py failed. aborting.  Schluss.
```

And now I don't have any clue what I should do. It's the first time I use a API and have zero experience with this. It would be very nice if someone of you could help me.

Comment: This isn't a guide for accessing [the Reddit API](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api). It's a guide for running *your own version of the software that powers Reddit*. You may want to have a look [at this](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API).

Comment: I'm so sorry for that, but I'm so  
inexperienced at this topic. However, I still don't know what I should do. I think I have to use a wrapper, but how do I implement it into my Java class?

Comment: There are probably many libraries out there. A [Google search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=java+reddit+library) is a good place to start. The API documentation [also lists a number of libraries, broken down by language](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API-Wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by running :

```
easy_install distribute
```